# Carregar html apenas 1 vez após o 3° parágrafo do texto com jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho esse exemplo mais gostaria que não repetisse, gostaria que aparecesse só uma vez!

```js
$('p').each(function(i) {
  var pos = i + 1;
  console.log(pos, pos % 3, this)
  if (pos % 3 == 0) {
    $('<div/>', {
      class: 'anuncio',
      html: '<div id="phtur">Div inserida!</div>'
    }).insertAfter(this);
  }
});

    $('#phtur').hide().delay(10000).slideToggle('slow');
    $('#phtur').click(function(){
        $("#phtur").slideToggle('slow');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>&nbsp;1</p>
<p>&nbsp;2</p>
<p>&nbsp;3</p>
<p>&nbsp;4</p>
<p>&nbsp;5</p>
<p>&nbsp;6</p>
<p>&nbsp;7</p>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Se trocar:

`if (pos % 3 == 0)`

por

`if (pos == 0)`

Resolveria seu problema

Comment: Valeu, deu certo! OBG